# Explicit 28 Lie algebra matrix representations of $Spin(8)$: Two half-spinor representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spin-geometry, dynkin-diagrams

A simple Lie group $(8)$ has 2 half-spinor representations and 1 vector representation (coming from standard vector representation of SO(8)), all of them have dimension 8. One can compose a representation of a Lie group, with an automorphism of the group to get another representation. In $(8)$ case, $((8))$ permutes above three representations and this we get an isomorphism of $((8))$ and $_3$. $(8)$ is the most symmetrical one in the sense that $((8))=S_3$ is the largest possible group.

My question concerns what are the matrix matrix representations of the 28 Lie algebra generators for the 2 half-spinor representations and 1 vector representation.

1. The vector representation of $Spin(8)$ is also the vector representation of $SO(8)$. We know the 27 of rank-8  matrices can be obtained by taking any two basis vectors $v_i$ and $v_j$ of 8-dimensional vector space, and assign $\pm 1$ along the off diagonal component with this matrix:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}  0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
   namely along the wedge product of the two basis vectors:
   $$v_i \wedge v_j = v_i \otimes v_j - v_j \otimes v_i.$$
   Include this matrix into the rank-8 matrix, we get $\frac{8 \cdot 7}{2}=28$ such set of matrix
   $$\begin{bmatrix} 0& \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0& \cdots &-1 &\vdots\\ \vdots & 1& \ddots & \vdots \\
   0& \cdots &  \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
   namely along the wedge product of the two basis vectors:
   $$v_i \wedge v_j = v_i \otimes v_j - v_j \otimes v_i.$$
   for any $i,j\in \{1,2,\dots,7,8\}$ with $i \neq j$.

Above we derive the explicit Lie algebra matrix representations of $Spin(8)$ also $SO(8)$: *vector representation*, with 28 Lie algebra generators of rank-8.

2. **Question ---** How do we derive the explicit Lie algebra matrix representations of $Spin(8)$: *Two half-spinor representations*? with 28 Lie algebra generators of rank-8?